# App crashing when accessing expression bodied property on instantiated object on Android, but not in Unity player

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a C# singleton class that creates a GameObject (unity) and auto instantiate itself the first time it is accessed from somewhere else...:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {

  private static MyClass _Instance;
  public static MyClass Instance {
    get {
      if (!_Instance) {
        _Instance = new GameObject().AddComponent<MyClass>();
        _Instance.name = _Instance.GetType().ToString();
        DontDestroyOnLoad(_Instance.gameObject);
      }
      return _Instance;
    }
  }

 public string SomeFunction() { return "Hello world"; }
 public string SomeArrow => "Good morning moon";
}
```

But when I try to use the Expression bodied member from another script file....:
`Debug.Log(MyClass.Instance.SomeArrow);`

The app silently crashes, actually I'm not sure exactly how to describe it, the frames keeps running, and UI elements are still interactable - but all C# code has stopped running.

Took me a while to find in the LogCat monitor that when trying to use the expression bodied property I get the following exception:

> ExecutionEngineException attempting to call method
> system.Linq.Expressions.Interpreter.LightLambda::MakeRun2<System.
> Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object,System.Int32 for which
> no ahead of time (AOT) code was generated.

This is not a problem when I run the game in the Unity editor, only when compiled and running on Android.

I have tried to crate a function instead of an expression bodied property:
`Debug.Log(MyClass.Instance.SomeFunction());`

And this works just fine - so eventually I could refactor a whole lot of code to move on, but ideally I would like to get the expression bodied properties to work on Android if possible.

I have also tried to create a expression bodied property and calling it within the class it self, so not `MyClass.Instance.ArrowThing` just `ArrowThing`, and this does not give any errors, only when calling it on the instantiated object.

In addition, it is worth to mention that I am trying to expose a lot of data points that are all cached in a `Dictionary<string, string>`, and parsed to different data types - so I can't really just create a lot of public variables and access those.

Unity editor version: `2021.3.8.f1`

Comment: `public string SomeLambdaExpression => "Good morning moon";` - this is not a lambda expression, this is expression bodied property.

Comment: To add to Guru Strons comment: An expression bodied property is identical to a regular get-only property. It generates the same IL code and whatever Unity does to get it to run on android will be identical to calling a regular getter, just like your `Instance` call.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated to question.

Comment: Can you include any of the original calling code that generated this error? I find it interesting the exception you posted mentions Linq, but I don't see any Linq in the code you shared.